# Install TF-Agent on Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi4

I'm having issues installing `TF-Agent` on Raspberry Pi 4B with Raspberry OS (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)) 32-bits.

When running `pip3 install TF-agents`, I get the following error:

> Building wheel for dm-tree (setup.py) ... error
> ...
> error: command 'bazel' failed with exit status 1

So I tried to Install Bazel from the source but I get:

> bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/_objs/protobuf_lite/arena.o:arena.cc:function google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::Init(): error: undefined reference to '__atomic_fetch_add_8'

What is the problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: try if this workaround helps you: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15278#issuecomment-520380265

Comment: Thank you Bruck1701, it did not work.